# Ubuntu 11.04 displays white lines when falling to prompt

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, graphics, console

First, I tried installing Ubuntu Server 11.04 on an older PC of mine in order to make it a file/ftp and web server. The installation went fine, but when I tried booting I only got a bunch of white lanes splashed across the display. It isn't frozen, since I can see the HD is showing signs of life during boot and after. After wasting two days on this, I decided I'd try my luck with the Desktop edition instead.

I was able to set everything up as I wanted with it, but the issue persisted - if I ctrl + alt + f12 I still get that same garbled, white lines screen. I know it is working, as I can access it remotely (smb, ftp or http). The same thing happens on boot as well - no Ubuntu splash or anything - either a black screen or a mess of random white pixels.

Installing or removing drivers doesn't make a difference. The monitor is an old CRT, don't know the exact model. It's maximum resolution is 1600x1200. The graphic card is an nVidia GeForce 7100 GS (64mb).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of boot options you should try:

`nomodeset` and `xforcevesa` - you can try each individually or together.

See my linked answer below on how to add a boot option to grub.

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834)